# How to hide team activity lines on Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I'm using Git to manage versions of my apps, but i don't have team so i don't need Team Activity lines at every method on Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, as pictures

[image: team activity]

Anyone can tell me how to turn off these things, because it slowdown Visual Studio and unnecessary!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That feature is called CodeLens. You should be able to right-click one of those lines and go to the feature's options where you'll see an option to disable it.